# chrome extension execute script wait for ajax response complete

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

in a chrome extension, in the `executeScript` function i click on the button, this button render content with ajax, i want wait content load and then click in an another button:
in the background.js script i have:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: tabs[0].url}, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: "scriptInjection.js"
        }, function (output) {
            if (output == 'test1') {
                sendData (output);
                //clearStorage();
            } else if (output == 'test2') {
                sendData (output);
                clearStorage();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i try a lot of things in `scriptInjection.js` for exmple i create a pause function like this:
in the `scriptInjection.js` file i have:

```
function pause(milliseconds) {
    let dt = new Date();
    while ((new Date()) - dt <= milliseconds) {
    }
}

if (document.URL == "...") {
    all = document.querySelectorAll('span.fc-title');

    for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        if (all[i].innerText == 'company') {
            all[i].click();
            var result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (result === true) {
        pause(2000);
        reserve();
        output = 'test1';
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#calendar > div.fc-toolbar > div.fc-right > div > button.fc-next-button.fc-button.fc-state-default.fc-corner-right > span").click();
        all = document.querySelectorAll('span.fc-title');

        for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
            if (all[i].innerText == 'company') {
                all[i].click();
                var result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (result === true) {              
            pause(2000);
            reserve();
            output = 'test1';
        }
    }
}
```

but in this way the script dose not wait until ajax content loaded, i use setInterval for reserve function but still it dose not work.
i use MutationObserver in the `scriptInjection.js` file like this at the start point of the `scriptInjection.js` but it dose not work:

```
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
        reserve();
      });
      observer.observe(document.documentElement, {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true});
```

and the reserve function:

```
function reserve(){
              let Shifts = document.getElementsByName("shifts");
              if (Shifts.length !== 0) {
                  for (let i = 0; i < Shifts.length; i++) {
                      Shifts[i].click();
                      break;
                  }
                  document.querySelector("#Btn").click();
              }

}
```

i read this link to use mutation observer "fjaguero.com/blog/using-mutationobservers-to-build-a-simple-extension/"
but i dont know where to place mutation observer in the chrome extension should i use it content script or in the execute script file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the executeScript functionality over the content script. Also, always prefer to use [the communication](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) between the content and background scripts.

Comment: tnx for help on github and your answer to this question, i use chrome.tabs.query in the function in the background.js file and setInterval for that function to run for example at 30 seconds in the row to refresh page and then click on the buttons and ... but i don't know how to this refresh for the page in content script file so i use executeScript functionality, the problem is how to wait for a content which load with ajax after script click on the button

Comment: thanks to the @fjaguero, the problem solved by using mutation observor in the content script and removing excute script function cause it called callback certainly after execute script and mutation observer closed

Comment: FYI, [this](https://github.com/fjaguero/twitter-replies-counter/issues/1) is where I posted another version of an extension with a mutation observer example